# Clean way to group 2 nested-loops/iterator in 1?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, nested-loops

Let's say we have 2 consecutive nested loops like this:

```
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    for r in p.runs:
        s = do_something(r)
        if something_else(s, r):
           r.text = another_function(s)

for table in doc.tables:
    for col in table.columns:
        for cell in col.cells:
            for p in cell.paragraphs:
                for r in p.runs:
                    s = do_something(r)
                    if something_else(s, r):
                        r.text = another_function(s)
```

**Is there a way to group them into one loop, without creating a new function?**  (In most cases creating a dedicated function, and call it in each nested-loop to avoid code duplication is the best, but here I'd like to explore other ways)

The only solution I've found is:

```
for r in [run for p in doc.paragraphs for run in p.runs] + \
           [run for table in doc.tables for col in table.columns for cell in col.cells for p in cell.paragraphs for run in p.runs]:
    s = do_something(r)
    if something_else(s, r):
        r.text = another_function(s)
```

**Is there a cleaner way to group 2 iterators together?**

Comment: Are the two iterables of the same size??

Comment: @Anwarvic not exactly same size (can be 100 vs 1000)